# Regex search group default value

Tags: google-analytics, regex-group

I need to extract language from the path for Google Analytics Content Group. The format of the url is `/:language/rest_of_the_path`, if the `/:language` part is missing it is default language (ex. `en`)

My regex is follwing

```
^/?(en|de|fr|)/
```

It works fine exept for the default substitution for the blank language.

Can this be achived by regex only?

Comment: not really because that part of the url isn't always reserved to the language. If the url begins straight with /rest_of_the_path and you have no way to differentiate that part from the language part, you are out of clues. So you could just match language as you did before, and if there's no match it means the language is blank. That's because you don't have the option: /[blank]/rest_of_the_path

Comment: I understand that. What I wanted to achieve is to have the Content group to be "en" and not blank

Comment: in case I correctly understand your issue, you could maybe use a different approach here. You could use a search&replace pattern looking for the first part if matches the en|de|fr and only in case it doesn't, replace the whole string with an added prefix /en/. I'll write in details in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Search for this pattern ^/(?!en/|de/|fr/)
And replace with /en$0

It uses negative lookahead and it replaces only when it doesn't find a recognized language at the beginning of the url

Comment: I get the point. But I do not know hot to apply two regexp one after another in Google Analytics Content Groups. There is only one field for regex expression. The Content group should be the regex group 1.

Comment: I was facing the problem as something strictly related to regular expression only. Unfortunately the problem is not clear to me when in the context of Google Analytics Content Groups. I can't help you further. I hope someone else will better address your issue.